# Get length and width of a television

Tags: algebra-precalculus, pythagorean-triples

TV measures $12$ inches diagonally, and the length is $2\times$ more than the width. What are the dimensions of the TV.

I thought:

$a = \text{width}$
$b = \text{height}$ 
$c = \text{diagonal}$

$c = 12$
$a = x$
$b = x+2$

so

$x^2 + (x+2)^2 = 12^{12}$
then solve for $x$.

But when I do, the answer is completely wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Pythagorean theorem implies that $\text{length}^2+\text{width}^2=\text{diagonal}^2$. The length is twice the width so the equation should be $$x^2 + (2x)^2 = 12^{2}\iff 5x^2= 12^{2}$$ which you can solve for $x$, noting that $x>0$.

Comment: You repeated OPs typo of $12^{12}$

Answer (score 0):

When you say "the length is 2x more than the width", does that mean the length is three times the width or twice?  If it is three times, your $b=x+2$ should be replaced by $b=3x$.  If it is twice, it should be $b=2x$.  At the end of the last equation it should be $12^2$, not $12^{12}$

Answer (score 0):

I have a related link that addresses this question but uses the tv screen aspect ratio within the formula calculation:

[What are the formulas to calculate tv screen height and width using the diagonal dimensions and aspect ratio?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2822283/what-are-the-formulas-to-calculate-tv-screen-height-and-width-using-the-diagonal/)